# Como hago para que no se me desborde el contenedor hijo de el padre

Tags: css, css3, scss, flexbox, css-grid-layout

Hola estoy usando una combinación entre grid y flexbox, me he creado una grilla en el home para que adentro de cada grilla crear cards con flexbox, ya emprece creando la primera card pero observen el resultado cuando minimizo el tamaño de la pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo html de mi componente home:

```
<div class="container-home">

  <div class="bienvenida">
    <div class="contenedor-bienvenida">
      <div class="contenedor-img"><img src="../../../../assets/images/home-welcome.svg">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <h2>Bienvenidos</h2>
        <p>Siente comodo administrando la información de tus empleados, de tus clientes y tus activos.</p>
        <p>Ir a soporte</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-1">Total empleados</div>
  <div class="card-2">Empleados</div>
  <div class="card-3">Planificador</div>
  <div class="card-4">Clientes</div>

</div>
```

Y este es el css que tengo, estoy usando scss:

```
.container-home{//Acá establezco la grilla del home
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ;

  .bienvenida{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .contenedor-bienvenida{
      height: auto;
      width: 80%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      .contenedor-img img{
        width: 150px;
      }

      .info h2{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: #032c55;
        font-size: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .info p{
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
    }
  }
  .card-1{
    background-color: cadetblue;
    grid-column: 3 / 4
  }
  .card-2{
    background-color: darkkhaki;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;


  }
  .card-3{
    background-color: dimgrey;

  }
  .card-4{
    background-color: goldenrod;
  }

}
```

No se si alguien sabe como podría hacer para que no se desborde la imagen y no se corte el texto en el area #1 de la grilla, ya probe aplicando `overflow: hidden;` en la clase `.bienvenida` y `.contenedor-bienvenida` pero así la imagen y el texto se corta mientras voy minimizando la pantalla.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: establece el width y height de la imagen en 100%.

Comment: Gracias pana me sirvio, había olvidado ese detalle